# Why this Linux programming C example code fails?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I'm trying to run the example from the Advanced Linux Programming book (Listing 3.4, page 51):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* Spawn a child process running a new program. PROGRAM is the name
 of the program to run; the path will be searched for this program.
 ARG_LIST is a NULL-terminated list of character strings to be
 passed as the program’s argument list. Returns the process ID of
 the spawned process. */
int spawn(char* program, char** arg_list) {
    pid_t child_pid;
    /* Duplicate this process. */
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid != 0)
        /* This is the parent process. */
        return child_pid;
    else {
        /* Now execute PROGRAM, searching for it in the path. */
        execvp(program, arg_list);
        /* The execvp function returns only if an error occurs. */
        fprintf(stderr, "an error occurred in execvp\n");
        abort();
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    /* The argument list to pass to the "ls” command. */
    char* arg_list[] = { "ls", /* argv[0], the name of the program. */
    "-l", "/", NULL /* The argument list must end with a NULL. */
    };
    /* Spawn a child process running the "ls” command. Ignore the
     returned child process ID. */
    spawn(" ls", arg_list);
    printf("done with main program\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I got:

```
an error occurred in execvp
done with main program
```

Any idea what's wrong here? (Using Ubuntu 10.10)

Comment: Could the space before `ls` be the issue?

Comment: Try `"ls"` rather than `" ls"`. Or even `"/bin/ls"`. Also, you can get information about the error from `errno`; why aren't you inspecting that?

Comment: Instead of (or in addition to) fprintf, add 'perror("Execvp failed");'. That'll print a human readable error message explaining what exactly happened.

Comment: @MihaiStancu yes, it's the space the problem... strange because in the console I can type " ls" and it works. Anyway, thanks! Please, publish as an answer!

Comment: @TomBrito: that's because your shell parses your input.

Comment: BTW @Tom, maybe you should change the title, ditch the *advanced* part - there's nothing advanced in that code unless it's from a "crash course" C tutorial and it's from the *advanced* chapter.

Comment: @MihaiStancu "Advanced Linux Programming" is the name of the book :)

Comment: @Tom: Point & case, if it's filed under *advanced* in a book, it means it's an advanced topic to start with, not an advanced topic in that field of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Tom's request:

The problem appears to be the (extra) space in the string that names the command.

Keep in mind that you are not calling the **bash** (shell) interpretor and giving it the string command. You are "naming" a command and in that respect it is analogous to naming a file, all characters are taken into account when comparing with the available commands (files).

Answer (score 1):

Quick guess, without validating: You must probably give full path to the ls command, like /bin/ls

Comment: A full path is not necessary as long as the binary can be found based on `PATH`. Since the code presented has a space as the first character of the executable name (which is likely an error), your full path solution would work but for the wrong reason. That being said, a full path is still preferable!

Answer (score 1):

The "program" argument you pass to your spawn function is incorrect. As specified by the man page of execvp:

The initial argument for these functions is the name of a file that is to be executed.

Here the file you want to execute is /bin/ls